# Apple Sign in flutter AuthorizationAppleID(null, null, null, null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apple-sign-in

I am trying to implement apple sign with flutter. I am getting all the values as null. First Time I got name and email id but got auth_id and id_token as null. Second time all the values came null like. AuthorizationAppleID(null, null, null, null, null)

```
_applelogin() async {
    provider = 'apple';
        final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
          scopes: [
            AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
            AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName
          ],
          webAuthenticationOptions: WebAuthenticationOptions(
            clientId: 'com.example.com',
            redirectUri: Uri.parse('https://My-Project.glitch.me/callbacks/sign_in_with_apple'),
          ),
        );
        print(credential);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

1. Check your server credential(.p8, PRIVATE KEY) file which is private key.
2. you can check 'authorizationCode','identityToken' than use like this code.

```
final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
          idToken: credential.identityToken,
          accessToken: credential.authorizationCode);

      // Sign in the user with Firebase. If the nonce we generated earlier does
      // not match the nonce in `appleCredential.identityToken`, sign in will fail.
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
```